# Converting Stream to byte array after asynchronously downloading in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am asynchronously downloading images from one web site.And I want to save list of images into IsolatedStorage. And stream is not serializable, so I have to convert it to byte array. But it is not reading Stream in while loop in **ReadFully**() method.

Here is how I am trying  to download images:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Headers["Referer"] = "http://www.website.com";
    request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
    {
        Stream imageStream = request.EndGetResponse(result).GetResponseStream();
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Set stream as the source of image
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
            bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
            image.Source = bitmapImage;

            // Convert stream to byte array and save in the custom list with the uri of the image 
            ls.Add(new DownloadedImages() { Image = ReadFully(imageStream), URI = uri });
            ds.SaveMyData(ls, "BSCImages");
        });
    }, null);
```

And here is the method for converting stream to byte array:

```
 public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

**Update**:

It is not getting inside the while loop. So the byte array is always empty.
[image]

Comment: What is the problem? What do you mean it is not reading the stream? Is there any exception? Is the stream length 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are consuming the stream `imageStream` in creating `bitmapImage` before passing to `ReadFully`.

First get the `byte[]`, then use it to form the image and to pass to `new DownloadedImages()`